# Flutter calling localToGlobal on listview item always return dx= 0.0?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello everybody I have a problem getting the global position of an item inside listview I don't know why the localToGlobal method always return an offset with dx=0.0 my goal is to animate a widget to specific item in listview so I need to know the global position of that target item.

```
... 
ListView.builder(
            
            itemCount: categoryState.list.length,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
              return CategoryItem(index:i);
            },
            shrinkWrap: true,
          ),
...

class CategoryItem extends StatefulWidget{
   const CategoryItem ({
    Key? key,
    required this.index});
 @override
  State<CategoryItem> createState() => CategoryItemState();
}
CategoryItemState  extends State<CategoryItem >{
GlobalKey _globalKey = GlobalKey();
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
         key:_globalKey,
         onTap:()=>getPosition(),
        child:Text(widget.index.toString())
     )
}
  Offset? getPosition() {
    RenderBox? object =
        _globalKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
  
      return object.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);//===Always return dx==zero
   
  }
}
```

Comment: what about `dy`?

Comment: dy is ok returns a value @pskink

Comment: so you always get zero as dx since your list view is aligned to the left side of the physical screen - if you wrap it with some padding for example you will get that padding as dx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dx` is always zero because that's the distance between the widget and the left side of the screen. In Flutter, Offset.zero is in the top left of the screen, the x axis increases to the right, and the y axis increases downward.